# How can I get a countdown timer working in a notification in android. Like in the image below

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image]

I want the notification to show a timer  which keep changing every second. It works fine below Android 12 but in Android 11+, the timer stopes when the app gets closed or the phone becomes idle(screen off).

I tried using Service but starting Android 12, due to some restriction on background operation the timer in the notification stops when the app gets close or the phone becomes idle.

Comment: Please check this https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 12, you need to request the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission for foreground services.

try adding this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

But remember, this may disturb User experience if you continuously display a notification which user can't dismiss.

I hope this might help...